# Using ".call" to create a new JavaScript object instead of "new"

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was trying the below commands on Chrome console. I am able to create the object using new(line 2 below) but using call doesn't work. Can anyone explain what could be the reason ?

```
function ObjConstructor(){ this.sample = 1};

let withNew = new ObjConstructor();

let usingCall = ObjConstructor.call({});

usingCall
undefined  //output that came on console, this is not a command

withNew
ObjConstructor {sample: 1} //output that came on console
```

Comment: Great Inputs Quentin, T.J.C, ".call" works smoothly when we use it with "this" while setting up inheritance because this is Object and new properties are added to it and no need to return anything ;)

Answer (score 3):

`new` does several things including:

- Creating an object
- Setting the `this` value to that object
- Causes the function to return that object by default

Your code:

- Creates an object manually with `{}`
- Sets the `this` value to that object with `call()`

… but doesn't do the last thing. There is no `return` statement in the function, so it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `call` is whatever the function returns. Your `ObjConstructor` doesn't *return* anything, so the result of calling it is `undefined.`

In contrast, when you use `new`, a new object is created and passed to the function, and unless the function returns a non-`null` object, the object created for `new` is the result of the `new` expression.

That's why the `new` version works but the `call` doesn't.

Also note that `call` doesn't create an object at all. In your `ObjConstructor.call({})`, what creates the object is `{}`, not `call`. It won't have `ObjConstructor.prototype` as its prototype. (`{}` is a raw object initializer, so the object will have `Object.prototype` as its prototype.)

Answer (score 0):

try this.
Or look at this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```js
var MyType = function(_param1,_param2){
this.param1 = _param1;
this.param2 = _param2;

this.ShowParam = function(){
  alert(this.param1+" - "+this.param2);
  }
}

var test = new MyType("PARAM TEST 1","PARAM TEST 2");

alert(test.param1+" - "+test.param2);


var test2 = new MyType("PARAM TEST 1.2","PARAM TEST 2.2");

alert(test2.param1+" - "+test2.param2);

test.ShowParam();
test2.ShowParam();
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs, I know about the Object but I want to learn of other alternatives to create Object.